# C++ cout only prints sometimes

Tags: c++

When I run this program and input, for example, the number 7, the final cout command only works occasionally. Otherwise, the program exits successfully but the result is not printed. Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double treble(double);

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Enter a number:" << endl;

    double numways;
    cin >> numways;

    numways = treble(numways);

    cout << "Your number trebled is: " << numways << endl;

    return 0;
}

double treble(double n)
{
    return n * 3;
}
```

Comment: Er, why do you put `using namespace std;` inside the function `treble`?

Comment: which editor you are using to compile or run ? I believe you are getting the out put correctly but it is not staying , because of return it is exiting the program . Try to do a "cin" before return 0 to pause the program and see the value.

Comment: Sorry, brand new to this, have removed it and the problem persists @YuHao.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans IDE on Fedora 20 @Nihar.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76626fbf5478ddd1).

Comment: try with this => put  "int temp; cin>>temp;" before "return 0;" to pause the program.

Comment: You need to describe what "only works occasionally" means. That's just a variation of "it doesn't work", which isn't an appropriate problem statement.

Comment: @Nihar Works every time now...

Comment: @remyabel I apologize for the vagueness. About 2/3 of the time I get the following output:

    'Enter a number:
    6
    Your number trebled is: 18

    RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 700ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms'

However, the other 1/3 of the time I get:
'Enter a number:
6

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 770ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms'

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the NetBeans IDE then... if you run the program from the command line, you should always get your output *providing* you do indeed input a valid number with no leading non-numeric characters etc. (with C++11 I believe you're guaranteed an output of 0 even without a valid numeric input, but with C++03 it's undefined behaviour).

Comment: user2243777 please remember to mark @Nihar answer as answer so it could help others.

Comment: @TonyD I've just tried compiling with g++ on the command line and it's working perfectly. No idea why NetBeans isn't working but thanks for the help.

Comment: @YuHao 'using namespace ...' can be scoped, so it is valid inside a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `using namespace std;` outside of all function declarations, right under your `#include` directives.  Also, when you say it's not printing, is it that the console is closing before displaying your result?  In that case, I would advocate using a simple `cin` to "pause" the program.  You can do it  exactly as @Nihar says, though I might suggest using a `string` instead of an `int` so that it doesn't break if you accidentally type something other than an `int`.

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double treble(double);

int main(){
    cout << "Enter a number:" << endl;

    double numways;
    cin >> numways;

    numways = treble(numways);

    cout << "Your number trebled is: " << numways << endl;

    string foo;
    cin >> foo;
    return 0;
}

double treble(double n){
    return n * 3;
}
```

Comment: Alright, thank you. My IDE is outputting 

Enter a number:
6

RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 770ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms

So I don't think the console is closing prematurely.

Comment: "You should put using namespace std; outside of all function declarations..." That is generally bad advice and has nothing no relevance here.

Comment: `std::cin.get()` is enough to pause the program, no need for a variable and `operator>>`.

Comment: I don't use NetBeans, so I can't help you there, but I can confirm that this works compiling with clang (on Mac OSX 10.9.5).

Also @juanchopanza there are certainly times that you would want to have `namespace` somewhere not at the top, but for such a beginner, I would advocate simply putting it at the top.  Namespace pollution is out of the scope of this discussion, as is the argument of whether it's smart to use `using namespace std;` at all.  I figured it'd be better to just leave it outside, rather than potentially have him run into problems if he tried to print somewhere other than main.

Answer (score 1):

try with this => put

```
int temp;
cin>>temp;
```

before `return 0;` to pause the program, because the execution finished (successfully) before the last output could be written to the console.

Comment: @luk32 maybe it is not formatted correctly but I think it solved OP's problem, so what is wrong with this?